# Move only error message on product view page

Tags: product, module, custom-options, products, error-message

can I just move the error message (You cannot use decimal quantity for this product.) under product.info.price?

Comment: Please add screenshot to understand what want you

Comment: Ok i'm sending screen. Can i move only this error message? when i move (in xml) element="page.messages", then all messages change position. 
https://imgur.com/a/QuTT2Ni

Comment: Error message which position move??

Comment: I would like to move under the button, i use this in xml file <move element="page.messages" destination="product.info.form.content" after="product.info.price"/>, but i want only change position error message, not success message.

Comment: this message showing qty is select decimal ??